# 3 way switch doesn't work with ceiling fan

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

[image]

This is my 3-way switch arrangement with a ceiling fan+light in my living room. The 3-way switches do not turn on/off the ceiling fan at all. The switches themselves seems fine, and there is 120 voltage coming up the white neutral wire, so I don't know what's going on. I should note that the 3-way switch and the ceiling fan have separate circuit breakers. Hence currently I can turn on/off the ceiling fan/light using the chains on it. Even if the 3-way switch themselves have current turned off in the breaker box. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Can you post photos or a diagram of how wires are connected in the ceiling-fan box?

Comment: the ceiling fan connections are 100% fine. Green is ground, black connects to black, white connects to white, and that stripped black wire I can connect the light fixture black wire to it, but then it won't light up. So I connected the light fixture black wire to the ceiling black wire, and it works by directly pulling the chain. The funny thing is the wall switches and the ceiling fan wires have different circuit breakers, so maybe they have nothing to do with each other? But then why on earth is there these two 3-way switches in the living room with the ceiling fan?

Comment: I need to know *all* the connections in that box...